# How to run program inside bash script and read the output in the script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I am writing a bash script to perform regular server maintenance. For this task, I am running a program that will take about 30 minutes to execute and will write to stdout every few minutes. I need the script to process these lines that the program writes in real time. I'm currently using a read-while loop to process each line like the following:

```
output=$($maintenance_command) 
while read -r line; do
    <processing logic>
done <<< "$output"
```

and it does work properly, but it does not do any of the processing until the program exits. Is there any way to run this in the background and read the output as it is written?

Comment: About `until the program exits`, what program are you talking about? This `$($maintenance_command)`?

Comment: Yes, correct. The script does not start going through the loop until $($maintenance_command) exits.

Comment: Ok. Then you should use a pipe: `yourCommand | while read -r line; do
    <processing logic>
done`

Comment: Try running something like this in your terminal: `ls -1 | while read -r line ;  do echo Line: $line ; sleep 1 ; done`. It's an example of using pipes and read the content line per line.

Comment: Using a pipe with `|` will put the loop in a subshell, so any changes made to variables won't affect anything outside the loop. I'd suggest `while read -r line ; do [processing logic] ; done < <($maintenace_command)` instead.

Comment: Interesting, even in this format it doesn't seem like the loop sees the lines until the program exits. 
`$maintenance_command | while read -r line ; do echo Line: $line ; done`

This does not print anything until $maintenance_command is complete. However if I just run $maintenance_command in the terminal I'm seeing messages regularly.

Comment: @Trevor maybe the problem is the buffer. I'm not sure if the *process substitution* the example given by frabjous can resolve the problem.

Comment: @Trevor if *process substitution* doesn't work then try: `stdbuf --output=L $maintenance_command | while ...` or `unbuffer $maintenance_command | while ..`.
I'm not sure if those commands will work. 
About the `$maintenance_command` what programming language is using? or is it a `bash` script?

Answer (score 0):

I was testing this script by using a python script that would output the same lines as the real program. However this behavior did not happen with the real program so must have been something with the python script.

Comment: Hi! Please, instead of creating an answer, edit the original question adding the new info.